omz reload in zsh widget
I am using zsh+oh-my-zsh and I am using the following code to change .zshrc using a hotkey and I am trying to reload omz after the change:
function f() {
  # ... update .zshrc here ...
  omz reload
}
zle -N f
bindkey "^[=" f  # Alt+=

However, hitting the hotkey closes the current terminal. This is a result of calling omz reload (which by itself callsexec zsh)
Is there a another way to reload zsh/omz without this causing the terminal to be closed?

does it work when bound to another key? My immediate reaction here was that your terminal emulator might be handling these keypresses before they reach your zsh

@MarcusMüller the problem is the omz reload. Replacing it with something else works.

could you add that (by means of editing your question) to your question? thanks!

This can be replicated with f() { exec zsh }, which is what omz reload eventually calls. Looks like replacing the shell while in the middle of a zle widget is the problem. It may be a zsh bug; I'm not aware of any way to work around it.

Code running in a custom zle widget (i.e. a zsh function that's bound to a key) runs with standard input connected to /dev/null. The reason for this is that zsh is in the middle of reading from the terminal, and commands run from widget should not interfere with this.
omz reload runs exec zsh to replace the zsh instance. Since standard input is connected to /dev/null, this zsh instance is not interactive, and reads commands from /dev/null, so it finishes running immediately (after executing zshenv files if present).
If you want to restart zsh from a widget, you need to redirect standard input to the terminal. I've minimally tested this (just exec zsh, not using oh-my-zsh) and it works, but it's possible that in some circumstances or on some systems this puts the terminal in a bad state, or the new instance of zsh restores a bad terminal state (but that's not a problem if zsh is run directly by the terminal emulator).
function f() {
  # ... update .zshrc here ...
  omz reload </dev/tty
}


